Draft standard post by ACF Data picker
I have a custom field named "fecha_borrado". The date is a date picker from Advanced Custom Field.
I have this code but don't work. Maybe i did some wrong?
I added too define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true); in my wp-config file
// expire offer posts on date field.
if (!wp_next_scheduled('expire_posts')){
  wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'expire_posts'); // this can be hourly, twicedaily, or daily
}

add_action('expire_posts', 'expire_posts_function');

function expire_posts_function() {
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post'), // post types you want to check
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $p){
        $expiredate = get_field('fecha_borrado', $p->ID, false, false); // get the raw date from the db
        if ($expiredate) {
            if($expiredate < $today){
                $postdata = array(
                    'ID' => $p->ID,
                    'post_status' => 'draft'
                );
                wp_update_post($postdata);
            }
        }
    }
}


you can't compare dates using strings, if ( "2024/01/01" < "2025/01/01" ) { doesn't work. The reason some code can do this is because it's handling dates as numbers e.g. seconds since the Unix epoch, not as strings. The code in your question won't scale anyway, it's easier and simpler to do this using meta_query so that MySQL does the date comparison, and to avoid setting posts_per_page to -1 as it means this feature will break once you publish more than a few hundred posts. You might also want to specify the published post status explicitly

also, the format you store the date in matters if you're going to have MySQL do the comparison. How you'd compare a date that's a string is a general PHP problem rather than a WordPress problem

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This code works perfectly!
function delete_expired_posts() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'fecha_borrado', 
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $acf_date = get_field('fecha_borrado', $post_id); 
        $acf_timestamp = strtotime($acf_date);
        $current_timestamp = time();

        if ($acf_timestamp && $acf_timestamp < $current_timestamp) {
            wp_delete_post($post_id, true); // Permanently delete post
        }
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
}

if (!wp_next_scheduled('delete_expired_posts_daily')) {
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'delete_expired_posts_daily');
}
add_action('delete_expired_posts_daily', 'delete_expired_posts');


Nice solve! You might consider editing this answer to include the details of what was wrong with the code in the question, and describe how the changes here correct the issue. This would improve the quality of the answer and help future visitors find and understand the changes.
